# Argparse use default value instead of argument

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to use the default value in Python argparse instead of the user specified argument. For example, here's an argument:

parser.add_argument('--fin', default='file.txt')

If a user calls --fin dog, that's obviously not a file, so I want to be able to use the default instead. How would I do that? Does argparse have a function that uses the default instead of the input argument? Also sorry for any typing mistakes, I'm doing this on a phone.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to access default arguments using the return value from `parser.parse_args()`.  More importantly, how is "dog" obviously not a file?  That's a perfectly valid filename on any modern operating system; file extensions are common but they are by no means required.

The only way to determine if something is or is not a file is by trying to open it.  If it fails, either it wasn't a file or you don't have access to it.

In this case, the best solution may be something like:

```
DEFAULT_FIN = 'file.txt'
parser.add_argument('--fin', default=DEFAULT_FIN)
```

And later on:

```
try:
    fd = open(args.fin)
except IOError:
    fd = open(DEFAULT_FIN)
```

Although I would argue that if the user specifies a filename on the command line and you are unable to open it, then you should print an error and exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
argument_file = parser.add_argument('--fin', default='file.txt')
args = parser.parse_args()
try:
    fo = open(args.fin)
except:
    fo = open(argument_file.default)
print fo.read()
```

But solution by larsks with constant seems better.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find the default value of an argument if you hang onto the identifier of the argument when you define it.  e.g.

```
In [119]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [120]: arg1 = parser.add_argument('--fin', default='default.txt')
In [121]: arg1.default
Out[121]: 'default.txt'
```

`arg1`, the value returned by the `add_argument` method is the `Action` object that the parser uses.  It has all the information that you provided to the method.  `arg1.default` is just one of its attributes.

So you could use `arg1.default` in your post `parse_args` code that checks whether `args.fin` is a valid file or not.

`larsks` approach is just as good, since you, the user, are defining the default in the first place.

You could also write a custom Action class, or argument type that does this checking.  There is a builtin `argparse.FileType` that tries to open the file, and raises an ArgumentType error if it can't.  That could be modified to use the default instead.  But this a more advanced solution, and isn't obviously superior to doing your own checking after parsing.